# XUnit tests and live unit tests in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, xunit

Having Visual Studio 2017 last version. I am unable run XUnit tests from test explorer in asp.net core Solution.
However, "dotnet test" works properly and Live Unit testing work properly as well.

I couldn't find any information how to fix my Visual Studio.
May you all can suggest me something?

Comment: _I am unable run XUnit tests from test explorer in asp.net core Solution_ - what is the symptoms?

Comment: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The following TestContainer was not found 'C:\src\yo\UnitTests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\Yo.UnitTests.dll'
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestContainerProvider.<GetTestContainerAsync>d__61.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at